# How to change text in table column using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code in my website is there any way to change text inside (td) tag in table using javascript

```
<div id="mvctable">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:2; text-align:Right;color:#ffffff;">
                    <img src="https://babilsport.com/wp-content/plugins/mechanic-visitor-counter/counter/mvcvisit.png"> Visit Today : 1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:2; text-align:Right;color:#ffffff;">
                    <img src="https://babilsport.com/wp-content/plugins/mechanic-visitor-counter/counter/mvcmonth.png"> This Month : 1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:2; text-align:Right;color:#ffffff;">
                    <img src="https://babilsport.com/wp-content/plugins/mechanic-visitor-counter/counter/mvctotal.png"> Total Visit : 1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: change text in which td?

Comment: All your `<td>` have an `<image>` inside and some text. What do you want exactly to happen with it?  If you just want to update the number in the text part it would be good to mark it with a `<span>` including an ID attribute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the td node you want to change via javascript. The most direct is to add an unique id attribute to the td you want to edit. Then use .textContent to set it.

```
document.getElementById("uniqueIdHere").textContent="newtext";
```

If you can't add unique ids then you will need to find via a known position or via the existing text in the td tag.

```
firstTD = document.getElementById("mvctable").querySelector('td');
firstTD.textContent="newtext";
```

You could get all of the TDs and loop through

```
tdElements = document.getElementById("mvctable").getElementsByTag('td');
for(var i = 0; i < tdElements.length; i++){
//do something to each td like
   tdElements[i].textContent = "something new...";
}
```

Need more info to give you more details.

Comment: If the textContent of the whole `<td>` is going to be changed then the image inside will disappear. This is not what OP might want.

Comment: @DavidThomas good point. I removed usage of it. Cheers!